Inspect all probabilities of BERTopic model
Say I build a BERTopic model using
from bertopic import BERTopic
topic_model = BERTopic(n_gram_range=(1, 1), nr_topics=20)
topics, probs = topic_model.fit_transform(docs)

Inspecting probs gives me just a single value for each item in docs.
probs
array([0.51914467, 0.        , 0.        , ..., 1.        , 1.        ,
       1.        ])

I would like the entire probability vector across all topics (so in this case, where nr_topics=20, I want a vector of 20 probabilities for each item in docs). In other words, if I have N items in docs and K topics, I would like an NxK output.

For individual topic probability across each document you need to add one more argument.
topic_model = BERTopic(n_gram_range=(1, 1), nr_topics=20, calculate_probabilities=True)

Note: This calculate_probabilities = True will only work if you are using HDBSCAN clustering embedding model. And Bertopic by default uses all-MiniLM-L6-v2.
Official documentation: https://maartengr.github.io/BERTopic/api/bertopic.html
They have mentioned the same in document as well.

Does this drastically increase the memory allocation of the function?

Yes, The increase in memory will be more. After enabling the new parameter the model will calculate probability for each topic across that document. The addional increase in memory will depends upon the no. of nr_topics.
